# How to prevent the "Symbol's function definition is void: error" when running emacs in the console?

Tags: macos, terminal, emacs

To disable the scrollbar in emacs I added (toggle-scroll-bar -1)  to the my .emacs file and it works great when I run emacs outside of console mode. However when I run emacs in the terminal I get the error Symbol's function definition is void: toggle-scroll-bar

I'm running Emacs 23.3.1

heres the trace when I run --debug-init

```
    1 Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-function scroll-bar-mode)                
    2   (scroll-bar-mode -1)                                                       
    3   eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/Users/neil/.emacs.d/init.el" nil t)  ;$
    4   load-with-code-conversion("/Users/neil/.emacs.d/init.el" "/Users/neil/.ema$
    5   load("/Users/neil/.emacs.d/init" t t)                                      
    6   #[nil "^H\205\264^@   \306=\203^Q^@\307^H\310Q\2027^@ \311=\2033^@\312\307$
    7   command-line()                                                             
    8   normal-top-level()
```

Comment: Emacs probably gave you a *Warnings* buffer telling you to run emacs with the `--debug-init` option to get a complete error backtrace.  Try that and add that information to the question.  Along with the Emacs version `M-x emacs-version`.  That chunk of code works just fine with Emacs 23.2.

Comment: @Trey Jackson, I added the details you requested, I seem to be running Emacs 23.1, so I'll try upgrading. Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: Very odd.  Ok, next test is running Emacs w/out your .emacs, `emacs -nw -q`, and then in the *scratch* buffer, type `(scroll-bar-mode -1)C-j` and see if you get an error.  That function is distributed with Emacs in the `scroll-bar.el` package, so I'm guessing your `.emacs` has something odd, or the Emacs wasn't installed properly.

Comment: I get this error upon doing that

Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-function scroll-bar-mode)
  (scroll-bar-mode -1)
  eval((scroll-bar-mode -1))
  eval-last-sexp-1(t)
  eval-last-sexp(t)
  eval-print-last-sexp()
  call-interactively(eval-print-last-sexp nil nil)

Comment: Here is my .emacs file http://pastebin.com/4mYE91Ne too

Comment: Ok, now how about `M-x find-library simple RET` - that should take you to where Emacs is installed, then `C-x C-d` to open a dired, and in that directory there should be a `scroll-bar.elc`.  Though the directions might fail if the Emacs wasn't installed with source lisp code...

Comment: @TreyJackson let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/897/discussion-between-bneil-and-trey-jackson)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I use this to turn off the scrollbar and toolbar when in a graphical display.

```
(when (display-graphic-p)
   (tool-bar-mode -1)
   (scroll-bar-mode -1))
```

FWIW. The emacs manual discourage the use of `window-system` as a predicate.

> Do not use window-system and initial-window-system as predicates or boolean flag variables, if you want to write code that works differently on text terminals and graphic displays. That is because window-system is not a good indicator of Emacs capabilities on a given display type. Instead, use display-graphic-p or any of the other display-*-p predicates described in Display Feature Testing.

http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Window-Systems.html

Answer (score 5):

While I think @neatonk's answer is best and covers all the bases, to specifically disable the scroll bar you can put the following in your `~/.emacs`

```
(if (fboundp 'scroll-bar-mode) (scroll-bar-mode -1))
```

Answer (score -2):

My guess is when you open `emacs -nw` emacs doesn't even bother to load scroll-bar.el. thats why it is having trouble to find the function `toggle-scroll-bar`.
may be instead if you put
`(scroll-bar-mode -1)`
probably work.

Comment: `(toggle-scroll-bar -1)` works just fine in `emacs -nw` for Emacs 23.2...